# Prove that $\log(1/(1-x)) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i}$

Tags: integration, generating-functions

I wish to prove that $$\log \left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i}.$$

The source I'm following [(Notes on generating functions by Michel Goemans, MIT 18.310, Section 8)](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18310S15/generating-function-notes.pdf) says to this can be performed by integrating both sides of:
$$
\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i
$$

On trying this, I get upto:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i \\
&\int \frac{1}{1-x}dx = \int\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i dx \\
&\int \frac{1}{1-x}dx = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \int x^i dx \\
&-\ln(|1-x|) + C = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{x^{j}}{j} + D \qquad \text{(set $j \equiv i + 1$)} \\
\end{align*}

which is clearly not what we were going for. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I'm primarily interested in the proof of the equality. It'd be cool if someone could show me how to prove this from the integral.

Comment: I mean, isn't it what you are trying to prove? Consider your last equation: $$-ln(|1-x|)=ln \left(\frac{1}{|1-x|} \right)$$ and since the series you began with only converges for $x\in(-1,1)$, then $|1-x| = 1+x$ $\forall x\in(-1,1)$. Therefore, you only need to consider the constant now: $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j} = ln \left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right) + C$$ Noting that when $x=0$ the sum becomes 0 and that $ln(1)=0$ you have $0=0+C$ therefore $C=0$ and you have your result

Comment: Recall that $-\ln (x)=\ln\left(\frac1x\right)$ and that the constants of integration are arbitrary so they can be combined into one. You could then substitute $0$ and note that $\ln 1=0=\sum 0 + K$, where $K$ is the combined constant.

Comment: Ah, right :) Thanks @Rafa and @Jam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much simpler proof, starting from the basic formula:
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i}\qquad (|x|<1),$$
and using that $\;\ln\Bigl(\dfrac1{1-x}\Bigr)=-\ln(1-x)$.